# Large Negative Decimal Values are getting rounded in spark DataFrame with Decimal Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Requesting help on below issue.
We are bringing data from Oracle using spark and one of the column data type is number(28,5) , for smaller values it is working fine , but if large negative values the data is truncated like -544205937126085.125 is converting into -544205937126085.100 , I tried in local but the issue and it is giving the same issue.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DecimalIssue {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
      .appName("Decimal Issue")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import  spark.implicits._


    val df = Seq((1234,1234.50),
      (1234,-544205937126085.125 ),
        (1234,200.567),
      (1234,-200.567)
    ).toDF("smallvalue","bigvalue")


    val df2 = df.select($"smallvalue",$"bigvalue".cast("decimal(28,5)"))

    df2.show(10,false)
    df2.printSchema()
  }

}
```

and the output from above code.

```
+----------+----------------------+
|smallvalue|bigvalue              |
+----------+----------------------+
|1234      |1234.50000            |
|1234      |-544205937126085.10000|
|1234      |200.56700             |
|1234      |-200.56700            |
+----------+----------------------+

root
 |-- smallvalue: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bigvalue: decimal(28,5) (nullable = true)
```

Ideally I am looking for the output

```
+----------+----------------------+
|smallvalue|bigvalue              |
+----------+----------------------+
|1234      |1234.50000            |
|1234      |-544205937126085.12500|
|1234      |200.56700             |
|1234      |-200.56700            |
+----------+----------------------+

root
 |-- smallvalue: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bigvalue: decimal(28,5) (nullable = true)
```

**EDIT:**
Even positive values also giving the truncated results.

**ADDED Data like JSON MESSAGE**

```
object DecimalIssue {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
      .appName("Decimal Issue")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

//    (1234, "1234.50"),
//    (1234, "544205937126085.125"),
//    (1234, "200.567"),
//    (1234, "-200.567")
    val customSchema = new StructType(Array(
  StructField("smallvalue",LongType,true),
  StructField("bigvalue",StringType,true)
))
    import spark.implicits._

    val data = "{\"smallvalue\":1234,\"bigvalue\":544205937126085.125}"
    val df = Seq( data
    ).toDF("data")

    val df1 = df.select(from_json($"data",customSchema).as("orig")).select("orig.*")

    df1.show(10,false)
    df1.printSchema()

    val  tryBigDecimal: String => BigDecimal = BigDecimal(_)
    val bigUDF = udf(tryBigDecimal)

    val bigDecimalUDF = udf(tryBigDecimal)
    val df2 = df1.select($"smallvalue", bigUDF($"bigvalue").cast("decimal(28,5)"))


    df2.show(10, false)
    df2.printSchema()
  }


}
```

But giving the same results

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now in the file `.json` numbers are reading as decimal values with the option `.option("prefersDecimal", true)`

file `.json`

```
{"smallvalue":1234,"bigvalue":544205937126085.125},
{"smallvalue":1224,"bigvalue":54420593712608534.12521},
{"smallvalue":2224,"bigvalue":5420593712608534.32521},
{"smallvalue":1114,"bigvalue":950420593712608534.521}
```

code

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object DecimalIssue {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .appName("Decimal Issue")
      .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val input = "/home/cloudera/files/tests/decimal.json"
    val data = sqlContext
      .read
      .option("prefersDecimal", true)
      .json(input)
    data.select(col("bigvalue").cast("decimal(28,5)"), col("smallvalue").cast("int")).show(truncate = false)
  }
}
```

and the expected output

```
root
 |-- bigvalue: decimal(23,5) (nullable = true)
 |-- smallvalue: long (nullable = true)

+------------------------+----------+
|bigvalue                |smallvalue|
+------------------------+----------+
|544205937126085.12500   |1234      |
|54420593712608534.12521 |1224      |
|5420593712608534.32521  |2224      |
|950420593712608534.52100|1114      |
+------------------------+----------+
```

You can find all the options in the `Spark` documentation:

[DataFrameReader](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader)

Comment: Hi Chema, Thanks for response . Now I modified the data like JSON Message but giving the same results.

Comment: You must know how data is coming(stream, .json, .csv and so on) because if you now change the format, why not .csv for example, or .xml. I said this because I think is important.

Comment: I changed my solution, I hope it can help you or gives you a clue to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Chema, I am getting these messages as JSON type from Kafka , and the Decimal data we are getting as Numeric only.and  I am using from_json  to read the data .

Comment: Hi!, when you read a .json you have options to change the default schema, for example: .option("prefersDecimal", true) I'll give you an example right now.